# How to exit bash script with case statement?

Tags: bash, bc

I have the following script :

```
#!/bin/sh
#Script bc : Celsius <-> Fahrenheit

echo "Temperature ?"
read Temp

echo "Celsius or Fahrenheit ?"
echo "c) Celsius"
echo "f) Fahrenheit"
read case;

Celsius=$(echo "scale=1;(($Temp-32)/9)*5;" | bc)
Fahrenheit=$(echo "scale=1;(($Temp/5)*9)+32;" | bc)

case $case in

c) read Celsius | echo "Temp. F : "$Fahrenheit;;
f) read Fahrenheit | echo "Temp. C : "$Celsius;;

esac
```

My problem is that, after the answer is (correctly) given, I am not brought back to the prompt. I have to make a carriage return in order to end that script and return to the prompt.

What do I miss ?

Thanks in advance

ThG

Comment: Look into the `switch` statement so you don't have to reinvent the wheel when creating menu-type scripts

Comment: In Bash, it's `select` rather than `switch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the "read" statements in that last `case` that are doing you in. Use

```
case $case in

c) echo "Temp. F : "$Fahrenheit;;
f) echo "Temp. C : "$Celsius;;

esac
```